# bare wires from pickups in ibanez diagram confusion

Tags: guitar, pick-ups, wiring

I am installing a two kill switch setup and am new to working within electric guitars.  I am working on an Ibanez Prestige from 2007.  I accidentally disconnected some soldering points so I used it as practice to mostly redo solder all wires plus additions that make up the kill switch parts.  But my question is regarding how to interpret the pickup wiring in this diagram.  I understand everything put the 'bare wire' as I don't see an additional wire coming from the neck or bridge pickup...  I suspect they within the wrap that goes around all wires coming from the bridge pickup and or neck pickup.  If they are in there, it will be easy to retrieve them...

**two question**
**1-** I just want to know for sure that they actually exist.  Maybe they are a conceptual aspect of the drawings.  Not sure.  Logically thinking its just a naked wire but I am no master at this yet!

and

**2** if they should go to ground (volume pod bottom) like the green wire next to it clearly does.  Here are two drawings that depict these 'bare' wires in different ways...[image]

[image]

[image]

I added the third picture.  That is exactly set up like mine.  Can anyone see where I might be sneding the wrong signal?  heheh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the bare wires (called "bare" because they have no insulation on them) go to the ground of the pot, which then connects to [what probably is] the ground of the output jack (that goes to the amplifier.)  Typically there's either a braid around the other insulated wires or a foil shield with a single bare wire for connections.  Either way, the most likely effect you'd have for omitting it is hum and noise on the signal and not lack of signal.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  If I now have a new question @Duston, do I make a new post?  I have everything wired as it should be except possibly the kill switch and the life switch.  I have no idea if the prongs on any of these vary in function to one another.  I imagine they have to.  My life switch only works in the middle three pickup selector settings (maybe correlates in some way with the fact that the middle life switch wire goes to the middle of the pickup selector?), and the kill switch just doesn't ever function.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I'd think that would work better as a separate question.